# What does it mean to take the complex integral $\int_{\alpha} \frac{1}{z}|dz|$?

Tags: calculus, integration, complex-analysis

$$\int_{\alpha} \frac{1}{z}|dz|$$
What does $|dz|$ means? I can't find it in my book but it appeared in my exercises. I must calculate this integral in the contour $\alpha(t) = re^{it}, t\in [0,2\pi]$.

Comment: Most likely means take $|dz|=|z'(t)|dt$ for some parameterization, that is treat as a complex weighted arclength integral.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By $|dz|$ people mean $|dx+idy|$ or in other words $\sqrt{dx^2 + dy^2}$.  Now, the question is, how do you integrate it.  If $z = \alpha(t)$ is a parametrization, then $dz = \alpha'(t) dt$.  Then $|dz| = |\alpha'(t)| dt$.  Why?  If you have $\alpha(t) = x(t) + iy(t)$, then $dz = \alpha'(t)dt = \sqrt{(x'(t))^2dt^2+(y'(t))^2dt^2} = \sqrt{(x'(t))^2+(y'(t))^2}dt$, which is something you can integrate.  The integral in $t$ is done in the positive orientation, say in your case from 0 to $2\pi$, so that $dt$ is positive.  In vector calculus $|dz|$ is usually called $ds$ which is the arclength measure.

Now in your setting $\alpha(t) = re^{it}$ so $|dz| = |ire^{it}|dt = r dt$.

You can always treat $dt$ and $dz$ and the like as if it were a small number (in the $dz$  case the number is complex), which it really is, so those formulas actually make sense.  It really is a function underneath.  So taking the absolute value of $|dz|$ is perfectly valid, and ends up with something we know how to integrate.